# PostMessage and HWND_BROADCAST

Tags: c, winapi, broadcast, sendmessage, postmessage

I'm trying to send message to all windows, by:

```
PostMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, 0x0401, 0, 0 );
or
SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, 0x0401, 0, 0 );
```

The problem is, that no window receives this message. Windows has own threads.
The question is... how to send message to all windows in my application, or why this function doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you determined that the windows are not receiving the messages?  Why are you sending 0x401, which is for private windows classes?  Messages in the WM_USER range should be sent only to specific windows that are of the class that recognizes that value.

Comment: Oh... I see... I change to WM_ACTIVATE and it works... Thanks... So, I know now why it throws error code 87...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The question is, how to send message to all windows in my application, or why this function doesn't work.

Messages in the `WM_USER` range (and incidentally, you really should stop using magic constants like `0x0401`) are reserved for private window classes. On the other hand `HWND_BROADCAST` results in the message being delivered to all top-level windows in the system.

These two facts conflict and `PostMessage` knows that. If `PostMessage` were to do your bidding then it would, for sure, deliver bogus messages to windows that would lead to undesirable behaviour. Hence `PostMessage` does not deliver your message to all the top-level windows.

Now, as mentioned, `HWND_BROADCAST` results in the message being delivered to all top-level windows in the system. You don't want that. You only want it to go to windows in your application. Which means that `HWND_BROADCAST` is not for you. If you want to deliver messages to specific windows in your application, you will have to maintain or obtain the list of windows, and deliver the messages one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use this to go to all top windows? This API doesn't work for child windows. You should also make sure you use value returned by RegisterWindowMessage rather a hardcoded value. This link should help you go to child windows.

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?130766-How-to-Send-messages-to-ALL-child-windows

Comment: Also, UIPI may be blocking the messages

Comment: Try throwing in a GetLastError call. If you get an accessed denied. You've got a privilege problem. You may also want to try look at an EnumWindow setup to study the problem in a debugger

Comment: That's strange... it throws error no 87... ( the parameter is incorrect )

Comment: Could it be that your message is an illegal value? I would implement the EnumWindows/EnumProc idea just to be able to watch the process more closely